# How to find two primes p and q where p and q are sufficiently large and q divides p − 1?

Tags: algorithm, math, primes

I want to know an algorithm to find two primes p and q where p and q are sufficiently large and q divides p − 1.

Comment: You might have more luck at [math.se].

Comment: Pick q and test 2q+1, 3q+1, 4q+1, ... for primality until you find a prime?

Comment: This should be easy to find a valid one? as if p is prime, so  p - 1 should be a complex number (as p - 1 will be at least divided by 2) except the case when p = 2 or 3. So you just need to choose a large p and  do the prime factorization for (p - 1).

Comment: How about `q=2` and `p=3`? More seriously, what do you mean by "sufficiently large"? sufficiently large for what purpose? The size of the numbers you're looking will have an impact on which methods are appropriate. E.g., @PhamTrung suggests finding a factorization for `p - 1`, but that becomes hard if `p` has hundreds of digits.

Comment: FWIW, generating Sophie Germain primes by simply picking a random `p` and checking whether `p` and `2p + 1` are both probable primes isn't  an unreasonable approach, up to a `p` of a few hundred digits. The (conjectured) density of such primes is proportional to `1 / (log p)^2`, so you'd expect finding (for example) a 1024-bit Sophie Germain prime to take fewer than a million trials: perhaps a few seconds to a few minutes on a modern machine with an efficient implementation.

Comment: Actually, make that a few seconds rather than a few minutes. A naive implementation in Python finds the first two S-G primes larger than 2**1024 in approximately 30 seconds on my under-endowed machine.

Comment: This question belongs on [maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good computer witch can do big calculs, you can use the list of firsts primes and compare each new prime - 1 to others.
It run show pair of prime witch p divides q-1, but it takes a little time.

If you want bigger numbers, instead of compare the new prime number with each primes already found,

you can compare the product of firsts prime and each first prime bigger than 100000. (the product of firsts prime +1 is prime, so you want compare (the product of firsts prime +1) -1 with a prime)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
</head>
<body>
<script>
var prime = [];
var result = [];
var minP=5000;
var minQ=10000;

// On cherche les nombres premiers jusqu'à max
var max = 200000;

for(i = 2; i <= max; i++) {

var j = 1;
var racine = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(i));

do {
j++;
} while(j <= racine && i%j != 0);


if(j > racine) {


for(k = minP; k <= prime.length; k++) {
 if( (i-1)% prime[k] ==0 ){
  result.push(i+' / '+prime[k]);
  document.write(i+' / '+prime[k]+ '<br/>');
  }
}

// On retiens les nombres premiers trouvés
prime.push(i);

}


}
console.log('prime=',prime, 'res=',result);
//document.write(result[result.length-1]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```